# Get the lat lng when plotting the polygon points

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to get the lat lng of the polygon while drawing the polygon on google map. Does anyone know what event is triggered when we plot the points of polygon.
Basically what I am trying to do is undo/redo function for the polygon. So when a user plots 2 points one then clicks undo then it should be able to delete 1 point on one click.

As the map click event is disabled while drawing a polygon how to get the lat lng points? Is it possible what I am trying to do? Can anyone please help me with this? Any links or examples that I could refer to?

Below is my code to draw polygon:

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: false,
    polygonOptions: {
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        editable: true,
        fillColor: '#FFF000',
        strokeColor: '#FFF000',
        geodesic: true,
        suppressUndo: true
    },
    polylineOptions: {
        editable: false,
        suppressUndo: true
    }
});

drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

Comment: how do you draw the polygon? via drawingManager or is it an editable polygon?

Comment: @Dr.Molle drawingManager but I have set editable to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

var myPoly;
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {

```
        myPoly = polygon;


        get_coordinates(polygon);//call to get coordinates


        //editing polygon function
        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', function() {

            get_coordinates(polygon);//call to get coordinates
        });



        var newShape = polygon.overlay;
        //newShape.type = polygon.type;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(newShape);
        });

        setSelection(newShape);

    });
```

and the get coordinate function

//function to get coordinates of polygon
        function get_coordinates(polygon){

```
        var full_path = [];//initialize array for set coordinates.
        polygon.getPath().forEach(function(elem, index){

            full_path.push(elem.toUrlValue());

        });

       return full_path;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this but in your solution I need to have a polygon first and after which I can get the co-ordinates. But in my case I need to get the points on the fly. Like for example I plot 3 points but then I realise that the 3rd point is wrong so I want to delete that point on click of some button. 
So in this scenario the solution won't work :(

Comment: in my second answer there is a function 'setSelection(shape);'; call this function and pass you polygon variable to the function. It will make your current polygon editable. then you can edit your polygon and save it. I think that is what you looking for. I am using this function to edit my saved polygon, and its working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

ok. I can give you all the functions you need. You can integrate last code with the following. And you cannot delete any point but replace it.

```
 var drawingManager;
  var selectedShape;
  var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#FF1493', '#32CD32', '#FF8C00', '#4B0082'];
  var selectedColor;
  var colorButtons = {};

  function clearSelection() {
    if (selectedShape) {
      selectedShape.setEditable(false);
      selectedShape = null;
    }
  }

  function setSelection(shape) {
    clearSelection();
    selectedShape = shape;
    shape.setEditable(true);
    selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
  }

  function deleteSelectedShape() {
    if (selectedShape) {
      selectedShape.setMap(null);
    }
  }

  function selectColor(color) {
    selectedColor = color;
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
      var currColor = colors[i];
      colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
    }

    // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
    // stroke or fill color as appropriate.
    var polylineOptions = drawingManager.get('polylineOptions');
    polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
    drawingManager.set('polylineOptions', polylineOptions);

    var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
    rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
    drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

    var circleOptions = drawingManager.get('circleOptions');
    circleOptions.fillColor = color;
    drawingManager.set('circleOptions', circleOptions);

    var polygonOptions = drawingManager.get('polygonOptions');
    polygonOptions.fillColor = color;
    drawingManager.set('polygonOptions', polygonOptions);
  }

  function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
    if (selectedShape) {
      if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
        selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
      } else {
        selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
      }
    }
  }

  function makeColorButton(color) {
    var button = document.createElement('span');
    button.className = 'color-button';
    button.style.backgroundColor = color;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
      selectColor(color);
      setSelectedShapeColor(color);
    });

    return button;
  }

   function buildColorPalette() {
     var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
     for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
       var currColor = colors[i];
       var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
       colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
       colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
     }
     selectColor(colors[0]);
   }

  function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.344, 114.048),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true
    });

    var polyOptions = {
      strokeWeight: 0,
      fillOpacity: 0.45,
      editable: true
    };
    // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
    // markers, lines, and shapes.
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      markerOptions: {
        draggable: true
      },
      polylineOptions: {
        editable: true
      },
      rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
      circleOptions: polyOptions,
      polygonOptions: polyOptions,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

        // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
        // mouses down on it.
        var newShape = e.overlay;
        newShape.type = e.type;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(newShape);
        });
        setSelection(newShape);
      }
    });

    // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
    // map is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);

    buildColorPalette();
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```